# Running dependent tests implicitly for command line execution of selective test in pytest

Tags: pytest

I have a test file ABCD.py with below sample tests

def test_a():
...Execute statements for test_a and possibly generate some outputs / logs

def test_b():
... checks some of the outputs generated by test_a

- test_b needs test_a to have run as test_b checks for some results that test_a generated in some form.

I want to selectively run test_b from command line, like

pytest ABCD.py::test_b

and somehow want test_a run first (without having to explicitly be mentioned on the command line) and then test_b.

The above is a minimalistic example and I have multiple linked tests that I want to be invoked implicitly before running the test of my interest from command line.

Cannot use fixtures here as I wont be able to have test_a as a test anymore. Cannot use dependency() as its useful only when running the whole file and wont help for command line execution of selective test with dependent / linked tests.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of plugins for pytest, including this one: https://pytest-dependency.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#basic-usage

It also makes sense as a plugin because dependencies between tests goes against F.I.R.S.T. principles.

Comment: I think "dependency" will not be useful for my scenario. It helps when we run the whole file and if the "dependent" test passes then only the one using that dependency runs. My goal is to be able to run a single testcase from the command line and not the whole file and still get the "dependent" tests run.